# ASP.NET MVC 2 Html.TextAreaFor not updating on Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form that lets the user enter in some text.  It will be longer than a few characters so I want to use a TextArea instead of a TextBox.

The Html.TextBoxFor works without issue, and the Html.TextAreaFor works when I create the entry, but does not store the new value when I edit it and shows whatever the value was before I went to edit it upon saving.

On Page:

```
    <div>
        <label>Work Performed:</label>
        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WorkPerformed)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkPerformed) %>
    </div>
```

Code Behind for Create:

```
    maintPerformed.MaintDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form["MaintDate"]);
    maintPerformed.WorkPerformed = Request.Form["WorkPerformed"];
    maintPerformedRepository.Add(maintPerformed);
    maintPerformedRepository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = maintPerformed.ID });
```

Code Behind for Edit:

```
    maintPerformed.MaintDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form["MaintDate"]);
    maintPerformed.WorkPerformed = Request.Form["WorkPerformed"];
    maintPerformedRepository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = maintPerformed.ID });
```

What am I missing on the edit side of things?

Comment: Code behind?  Do you mean Controller?

Comment: check if Request.Form["WorkPerformed"] is carrying correct value or use viewmodel as paramter to ur action method as darin said so it could be populated by virtue of default model binder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you are redirecting to the `Details` action. So make sure that `maintPerformedRepository.Save()` actually does something and most importantly in your `Details` action look what value is fetched from the data store. I suspect that either the database is not updated or in your `Details` action you are fetching a wrong value for your model.

Remark: Instead of writing the ugly `DateTime.Parse(Request.Form["MaintDate"]);` and `Request.Form["WorkPerformed"];` pass your view model as argument to your controller action and let the model binder populate it from the request values.